# C# I Need A Control That Works Like A DataGridView But Allows Me To Add A Custom Control

Tags: c#, datagrid, custom-controls

I have an application that needs to display 1 to N custom controls in a grid (one control per row) and allow the user to select one row at a time.

I tried using DataGridView but that only allows Text, Button, Checkbox, ComboBox, Image, and Link.

Is there a control similar to DataGridView that allows me to insert any arbitrary custom control?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `custom column` by extending the `DataGridViewColumn` and `DataGridViewCell` classes. Have a look at MSDN article - [How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80%28VS.80%29.aspx)